Problem with thr installing GUT plugin for Godot 4.2
I got some strange bug with installing GUT plugin.
After installing it from official AssetLib, I can't add it to scene like a node.
You can see that it is not a scene or a node (PrtSc from Godot4.2).
I tried to delete folder ".godot" and reinstall godot project.
Did someone have the same issue?
